# Origin of the Intelligence question?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

What are the roots of the Intelligence question, i.e. since when do "humans" think about what "Intelligence" means and where it actually comes from?

I did some digging in the greek philosophy around the topic of "Nous", though it seems the roots go way deeper - unfortunately not finding any proper sources. Hence: Does anyone know about the "Origin of the Intelligence question?"? (*Preferably with sources*)

Comment: You mean written sources talking about human reasoning ability [before Homer and Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nous#Pre-Socratic_usage)?

Comment: I mean since when humans are able to think about the ability that enables them to even pose this question. In the daily Language usage being called “Intelligence”.

Comment: I.e. I wanted to introduce my essay with the statement: “The question of ‘intelligence’ originates [x year ago] and has made tremendous developments”

Comment: My guess is that people were able to since prehistoric times, our brains did not change much since then. I am trying to formulate a question that would be more concretely answerable.

Comment: The term "reason" would be the best to look into.